# Store output of sed with command substitution in it into a variable

Tags: bash, shell, sed, substitution

Consider a string

```
Message="Hello WoRld"
```

I would like to substitute the upper case `R` by the lower case `r`

```
echo "$Message" > file.txt
NewMessage=$(sed 's/R/r/' file.txt)
```

works fine! The following would work as well

```
NewMessage=$(echo ${Message} | sed 's/R/r/')
```

But my first reflex was to use command substitution

```
NewMessage=$(sed 's/R/r/' <("$Message"))
```

but it does not work. Why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your cmd-sub version *was* missing the leading `M`?

But you want

```
NewMessage=$(sed 's/R/r/' <(echo "$Message"))
```

OR your shell may support

```
NewMessage=$(sed 's/R/r/' <<< "$Message")
```

---

**edit**

and the simplest, most widely supported solution would be much simpler

```
NewMessage=$(echo "$Message" | sed 's/R/r/')
```

If you need absolute stone-age compatibility to Bourne Shell (true `/bin/sh`) then you'll have to forego the nice `$(..cmdSub)` syntax and use back-quotes for command-substitution:

```
NewMessage=`echo "$Message" | sed 's/R/r/'`
```

IHTH

Comment: Sorry for the leading `M`. That was a typo (fixed now). Thank you, I get the error now. I'll check this answer when I can. (+1).

Comment: Glad that helped. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using `bash` 4, you don't need `sed`:

```
NewMessage=${Message,,R}
```